# How to disable entire Primefaces dataTable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

Is there a way to disable the entire `dataTable` in Primefaces? Somebody suggested to use the `editable` component but that doesn't seem to help.

> `#{conversionRatesBean.readOnlyUser}` is the code that filters out the group of users.

I am using **Primefaces 3.5** and **JSF 2.1.6**

If not in Primefaces, can somebody suggest some solutions in jQuery?

```
<div class="grid_12 width_75_pc margin_left_auto" > 
    <div class="datatable">
        <p:dataTable editable="#{!conversionRatesBean.readOnlyUser}" id="conversionRateTable" var="row" value="#{conversionRatesBean.rowNames}" rowIndexVar="rowIdx" styleClass="projectTable table-container">
            <p:column headerText="" styleClass="#{rowIdx  == -1  ? 'itPanelGreen' : 'ui-widget-header'} textAlignCenter valign-middle width_20_pc column_name" >
                            <h:outputText value="1  #{row.name} =" />
            </p:column>
            <p:columns var="column" value="#{conversionRatesBean.colNames}" headerText="#{column.name}" columnIndexVar="colIdx"
                                    styleClass="#{rowIdx == colIdx ? 'itPanelGreen' : 'textAlignCenter'}">
                  <input:decimalField beanValue="#{conversionRatesBean.conversionMap[row][column].conversionValue}"
                      errorMsg="#{msgs['errorInvalidValue']}"
                      rendered="#{rowIdx != colIdx}"
                      decimalFields="4"
                      errorDecimal="#{msgs['packaging.error.number.decimals']}"
                      styleClass="textAlignRight "
                      maxLength="9"/>
            </p:columns>
        </p:dataTable>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="actions grid_12 alpha">
        <p:commandButton id="saveBtn" value="Save" update="conversionRateTable"
            action="#{conversionRatesBean.save}"
            oncomplete = "qt.removeSavedState();"
            disabled="#{conversionRatesBean.readOnlyUser}"
            styleClass="js-saveButton button" onstart="screenUtils.triggerRequired(); if(screenUtils.errorsOnPage()){return false;}"/>

        <pretty:link mappingId="rateSelection" styleClass="displayInlineBlock margin_top_5">
            <f:param value="#{conversionRatesBean.rateId}" />
            <h:outputText value="#{msgs.backtoOverView}" styleClass="linky margin_left_10" />
        </pretty:link>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you want to disable exactly? The input fields or the selection?

Comment: the entire dataTable

Comment: I don't think you can disable the entire dataTabel. You can disable the selection or the editableMode. MAyb blockUI can help you. You could implement a blockUI and create a small workaround. https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/blockUI.xhtml

Comment: The idea is to disable the dataTable permanently based on certain conditions. `blockUI` has a different purpose and it would disable the dataTable only until the server returns a response. Could you share your workaround that might prove helpful ?

Comment: check this: http://showcase.omnifaces.org/taghandlers/massAttribute

Comment: any CSS+Javascript hack, apart from omnifaces ?

Comment: CSS + javascript is pure client-side and dangerous (never trust the client)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue by doing this:

Added the following line of code in the **`decimalField.xhtml`** page, which was essentially a composite implementation for the input tag.

> ```
> <composite:interface>
>    <composite:attribute name="disabled" default="#{false}"/>
> </composite:interface>
> ```

Thereafter, from the using page **`conversionRates.xhtml`** called the composite attribute as below:

> **`<input:decimalField  disabled="#{conversionRatesBean.readOnlyUser}"/>`**

Comment: But if the dataTable contains only input fields and if they get disabled, isn't it as good as the entire dataTable being disabled ?  Btw, I couldn't find any way to completely disable the entire dataTable in either Primefaces or jQuery. Share us your thoughts if you got a different view.

Comment: Yes but then your question is totally irrelevant since it normal disabling things. And posted a 'solution' as a comment. Did you read it?

Comment: if you got a solution that could well suit the question header, please feel free to post it... and I would be happier to accept it.

Comment: It's not specifically about getting 'my comment' accepted as an answer, you might do that as well. It is about your question being different from the problem you seemed to have (at least according to your answer) so the wrong effort was put into it and that is not always pleasant to experience.. Cheers